# How to implement multiple delete with bulkDelete

Tags: go, elasticsearch, bulk

I have array of Profile Ids (uid) and need to delete all these profiles with 1 request.

Here is my code.

```
func MultipleDeleteFromElastic(index string, inType string, uid string, ct interface{}) error {
    client, err := GetElasticCon()
    if err != nil {
        ElasticConnectError.DeveloperMessage = err.Error()
        return ElasticConnectError
    }

    deleteReq := elastic.NewBulkDeleteRequest().Index(index).Type(inType).Id(uid)
    _, err1 := client.Bulk().Add(deleteReq).Do(context.Background())
    if err1 != nil {
        ElasticConnectError.DeveloperMessage = err1.Error()
        return ElasticConnectError
    }
    return err1
}
```

What does the bulkDelete need? How I can pass an array in BulkDelete?

I have no idea if I doing this right (obviously I am not).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [Delete by query with Go](http://programming.freeideas.cz/2017/03/07/golang-elasticsearch-delete-by-query-usage/)?

The delete by query API from ES lets you delete all the objects that satisfy certain query.

Just be careful. If you don't have any query, all the objects in the index will be deleted. You know, like the DELETE without a WHERE joke :P

Hope this is helpful :D